# Display multiple IE windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer

I have multiple IE windows open. When I select one from the task bar, all the others are minimized. I would like to display multiple IE windows side by side.

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer are you running?

Comment: "I have multiple IE windows open" - are you sure you don't just have 1 IE _window_ open with many _tabs_?  There should be nothing preventing you from having two IE _windows_ visible at once, arranged however you'd like... If you want the tabs separated, then just grab one and tear it out into it's own window.

Comment: Keep in mind that newer versions of Internet explorer show previews of each tab from the taskbar, even if the tabs are all in the same window. Make sure you're actually dealing with separate windows and not just different tabs.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see 2 windows side be side choose the first windows and drap it to the right / left border of the screen, or click <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>left arrow</kbd>  or <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>right arrow</kbd>.
Do the same to the second windows, but on the opposite side.

If you want to have more then 2 windows simultaneously just resize them so won't be full screen (drab the titbar of the window or click the `Restore Down` key, near the `Close` key on the top right).